# How to create a header in Word with different color

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to create header for word documents in a folder.The header content is same,"XYZ company" in the center and "For internal use" in the right.
Currently I use below code to do it.

```
Sub change(FolderPath As String)
   Dim Fs, oFolder, f1, f2, f3, FColloll, s
   Set Fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set oFolder = Fs.GetFolder(FolderPath)
   Set Fcol3 = oFolder.Files
   For Each f3 In Fcol3
     If f3 Like "*.docx" Or f3 Like "*.pptm" Then 
        'Set Variable equal to Header Range
        Set file = Documents.Open(filename:=f3.Path)
        Set HdrRange = ActiveDocument.Sections.Item(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
        HdrText = "XYZ COMPANY          For Internal Use "
        HdrRange.Text = HdrText
        ActiveDocument.Save
        ActiveDocument.Close
       End If
     Next
End Sub
```

It worked but Now I have a new requirement, I want to change font color of  "For Internal Use"  to red.
I can use font.colorindex to change color. But that work on the whole header range, How do I set the  "For Internal Use" as range and modify it ? Thx.

Comment: Please clarify - in your question - whether you want to change the font colour in the documents you have already modified, or for documents you're about to modify. The coding requirements are quite different.

Comment: @ macropod I have a folder with many word documents. I want to change their headings to the text.

Comment: You haven't provided the required clarification - read my previous comment - and provide that clarification *in your question*.

Comment: @macropod I want to change the font color for documents I want to modify.

Comment: You seem determined not to answer a *simple* question.

Comment: @macropod I'm not sure what you mean already modified or about to modify. What I'm doing is create a macro in document A, and use it to modify documents in folder B. Is this about to modify?

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
Const cFIU = "For internal use"

Set HdrRange = ActiveDocument.Sections.Item(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
i = InStr(HdrRange.Text, cFIU)

For k = i To i + Len(cFIU) - 1
    HdrRange.Characters(k).Font.ColorIndex = wdDarkRed
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Sub ColorHeader1()
    With ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
        .Text = "XYZ COMPANY          For Internal Use "
        .SetRange .Characters(InStr(.Text, "For")).Start, .End
        .Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
    End With
End Sub
```

or

```
Sub ColorHeader2()
    HdrText = Array("XYZ COMPANY        ", "For Internal Use")
    With ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
        .Text = HdrText(0)
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        .Text = HdrText(1)
        .Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
    End With
End Sub
```

**Edit2**

```
Sub ColorHeader1()
    With ActiveDocument.Sections(1)
        With .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
            ' add tabs to text for further alignment
            .Text = vbTab & "XYZ COMPANY" & vbTab & "For Internal Use"
            .SetRange .Characters(InStr(.Text, "For")).Start, .End
            .Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
        End With
        With .PageSetup
            pw = .PageWidth     'get the width of the page in points
            rm = .RightMargin   'get the distance (in points) between the right edge of the page and the right boundary of the body text
            lm = .LeftMargin    'get the distance (in points) between the left edge of the page and the left boundary of the body text.
        End With
        With .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.ParagraphFormat.TabStops
            .ClearAll   ' deletes previous tabstops
            .Add Position:=pw / 2 - lm, Alignment:=wdAlignTabCenter ' add center tab for "XYZ COMPANY"
            .Add Position:=pw - rm - lm, Alignment:=wdAlignTabRight ' add right tab for "For Internal Use"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thx.That work.I have one more question if you don't mind.  I want " XYZ Company" at center and "For Internal Use" at right. Can I do that through fomat?

Comment: yes you can do it with `ParagraphFormat.TabStops` - see Edit2 solution

Comment: @АлексейР - it would be better if you used `.InsertAlignmentTab` as this will give the correct alignment regardless of page layout.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt, thanks for the suggestion. I tested `.InsertAlignmentTab wdCenter, wdMargin` and `.InsertAlignmentTab wdRight, wdMargin`. This method has a disadvantage - errors in determining the center of the page and the right edge of a few millimeters. Using `ParagraphFormat.TabStops` gives better positioning accuracy in both portrait and landscape orientation. The advantages of using `.InsertAlignmentTab` are less computation and code. However, neither method allows you to keep the exact position when you flip the sheet.

Comment: @АлексейР - you're not comparing the same things. `.InsertAlignmentTab wdCenter, wdMargin` centers the text between the margins. That is different to centering to the page, as you do in your code, which takes no account of the margin settings. However, if the left and right margins are equal there is no difference.